# Result with auto layout in a UITableView different when starting the app and once the app is running

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have a UITableView that I created in the Interface Builder. Inside are dynamic cells. I added the constraints like this (this method is called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`) :

```
@IBOutlet weak var rowView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var flagImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var computedRateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var historyButton: UIButton!

func buildConstraintsFor() {
    let viewsDictionary = ["rowView": rowView, "flagImageView": flagImageView, "view1": computedRateLabel, "historyButton": historyButton]

    rowView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    flagImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    computedRateLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
    historyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    rowView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    flagImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    computedRateLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    historyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

    // remove constraints
    rowView.removeConstraints(rowView.constraints())
    historyButton.removeConstraints(historyButton.constraints())

    // add constraints
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[flagImageView]-[view1]-[historyButton]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-1-[flagImageView]-1-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-1-[view1]-1-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-1-[historyButton]-1-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

    // size
    historyButton.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[historyButton(==25)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[rowView(<=68)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[rowView(>=67)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    flagImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: flagImageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: flagImageView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following which is what I want
[image]

When I scroll the TableView and when rows disappear and reappear (or when I go to another viewController and come back) I get the following:

[image]

I don't understand why.
If I add this:

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.width
rowView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[rowView(==\(width))]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

It seems to solve the problem but doesn't work anymore when I go landscape.

Did I do something wrong when I did the layout?

**EDIT:**

When I print the description of all the constraints of rowView after adding them here is what I get:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009f3b0 UIImageView:0x1701f5a00.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0.leadingMargin>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009f6d0 H:[UIImageView:0x1701f5a00]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x13760f7f0'12 106,98']>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009f9a0 H:[UILabel:0x13760f7f0'12 106,98']-(NSSpace(8))-[UIButton:0x137634b60]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009dec0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x137634b60.trailing>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098920 V:|-(1)-[UIImageView:0x1701f5a00]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009a4a0 V:[UIImageView:0x1701f5a00]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174098dd0 V:|-(1)-[UILabel:0x13760f7f0'12 106,98']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174099550 V:[UILabel:0x13760f7f0'12 106,98']-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283c00 V:|-(1)-[UIButton:0x137634b60]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1702837a0 V:[UIButton:0x137634b60]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283d90 V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0(<=68)]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170283de0 V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1701968c0(>=67)]>
```

Comment: check this approach:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231390/uitableview-strange-layout-behavior-changes-on-scroll/29327082#29327082][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231390/uitableview-strange-layout-behavior-changes-on-scroll/29327082#29327082

Comment: Doesn't really help as for me, I set all the constraints (I don't see which one is missing) and the link provided in the answer doesn't talk about constraints programmatically but in the IB

Comment: Try to add autosizingMask to rowView rowView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything

Comment: I made an update with new screenshots

Comment: under // remove constraints add rowView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) which avoids automatic way for Xcode to calculate constraints.

Comment: Set the same for other layouts such as image,label and button also to remove any automatically added constraints by Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution I found as it might help. Thanks Ram for your help.

Indeed, when you're using auto layout programmatically, don't forget to add `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on every component you are adding a constraint to.

In my case I had created the constraints in the Interface Builder, and as I needed to remove a UILabel from my rows during run time, I had to recreate the constraints for my rows (such as aspect ratio, width or height). So as I wanted to change ONLY the placement of my components in my rows, I didn't need to recreate the constraints for `flagImageView` or `historyButton` as long as I don't remove them.

But I needed to remove the constraints from my `rowView` as I was adding new ones and removing some. This `rowView` is actually the `contentView` of my `UITableViewCell`. By removing the constraints, I was also removing the constraints linked to its superView which is actually the `UITableViewCell` itself. So my `contentView` was not the same size as its parent. So I just needed to add these two lines:

```
rowView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[rowView]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
rowView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[rowView]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```