# Autolayout - UITableViewCell with ImageView - Margin?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a problem when i will try to make a left/top/bottom margin with an UIImageView in a cell. It don't care what i will try to set as Top/Bottom/Left Space, i will always get the same result -> all Images are without any margin.

I have a fixed height and width, i will just want to add  top/left margin.

[image]

Is there any way to force the Autolayout to add a margin here?

Thanks in advance for any tips.
**Edit:** 
Thanks for you answer. Ill tried it, but its still not working. There is always no margin between cell and image:

Here are my constraints. (ill just take 8px as space to superView)

[image]

Comment: Getting auto layout to work on a UITableViewCell is to ensure you have constraints to pin each subview on all sides — that is, each subview should have leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints.check the link for similar type of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231390/uitableview-strange-layout-behavior-changes-on-scroll/29327082#29327082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i could't get quite to work on this issue. but i am sure that it will going to work if you try this things in your code.

[Using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Edit:

Set the new UIImageView size and position to the values shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Now select UIImageView and add following contraints.

Set **leading**, **top** and **bottom** to 20.

Set **width** and **height** to 100.

Make sure that **Constrain to margins** is not checked.

Tap the **Add 5 constraints** button.

[image]

Select the `image view` to show its constraints, and then select its **bottom** constraint to edit it. In the attributes editor, change its **Relation** to **Greater Than or Equal** and its **Priority** to 999.

[image]

Next, select the **image view** to show its constraints and then select its **height** constraint. In the attributes editor, change its **Priority** to 999.

Likewise, select the image view’s **width** constraint and change its **Priority** to 999.

To set following constraints, you will get you answer.

Comment: Thank you, but its not working. Ill edited my start post

Comment: @derdida, are you sure you set the proper  constraints that i was shown in post. because here is working fine.

Comment: @derdida, can you please check that your `UIImageView` mode is `Aspect Fit`.

Comment: Thanks - already checked and changed it to aspect fit - and the same problem. Can u maybe upload (github?) your projekt, so i can take a look at it?

Comment: All Constraints should be fine, i am using Autolayout multiple times, and normally it works fine - could this be a problem because i am doing an universal app? There are a few (greyed out) constraints in my view.

Comment: @derdida Go to `Document Outline`  remove all conflict constraints.

Comment: There are no conflict constraints. They are all blue and are looking fine - but there is still no space between image and cell.

Comment: @derdida do you want to add separate between two images, Am I right?

Comment: Hmm totally stupid, but: ill deleted my UITableViewCell, created everything new - and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];/// change size as you need.
    CGRect frame = separatorLineView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 5.0;
    frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
    separatorLineView.frame = frame;
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
    return cell;
```

**OR**
Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

Now use these constraints

**storyboard**
[image: 1st image]

**simulator**
[image: 2nd image]

This might helps you :)

Comment: That is not a good solution - it should work only with Autolayout.