# unable to Set Height of the CustomCells in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have many customCells each cell may have a button which acts like a textbox or textArea.When the View loads they have very less height.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad();

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
   self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

And i have the following constraints defined on the cell [image]

Will auto layout work with prototype cells at all?
If not how to implement this?
I tried with HeightforrowAtIndexPath method layout looks good only after scroll. Initial load of the view will not come with good layout.

below is my code for this.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if (eleData.elementType=="apple")
    {
        return 90;
   }  
 else if (eleData.elementType=="banana")
    {
        return 50;
   }     
else  
{
  return 30;
}

}
```

Any suggestions .
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick google search gives you your answer...

[UITableView dynamic cell heights only correct after some scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971147/uitableview-dynamic-cell-heights-only-correct-after-some-scrolling)

You need to add layout if needed before returning your cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Still sometimes the same issue is coming ... How can i prevent this?

Comment: Sometimes? When does it happen exactly?

Comment: on scroll up and down

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231390/uitableview-strange-layout-behavior-changes-on-scroll

Comment: I gave constraints on all the prototype cells and now its working fine. Thank you for your help.